# How do I process arrays within an array?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an array of arrays of arrays as JSON, a sample included below where

```
F1 = Feature #1
P1 = Point #1
X / Y = Coordinates
```

so `F1P1X` is the X-value of point #1 of feature #1.

```
[
    [
        [F1P1X,F1P1Y,null],
        [F1PnX,F1PnY,null]
    ],
    [
        [F2P1X,F2P1Y,null],
        [F2PnX,F2PnY,null]
    ],
    [
        [FnP1X,FnP1Y,null],
        [FnPnX,FnPnY,null]
    ]
]
```

Here is the code I use to get the above JSON from a file:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("ABC.json");
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken token = obj.SelectToken("$.features[?(@.name == 'X')]['XY']");
var paths = JToken.Parse(token.ToString()).SelectToken("XYZ");
```

Next, I need to build strings using the various arrays. How do I get the second-level array (the feature) so I can process its innermost arrays (points on the features)? The end will be `List<string>` where each string is a feature (second-level array in the JSON) and the innermost array are the points that make the feature. I can handle the string manipulation but first I need to get the arrays out of the JSON.

Comment: That's not valid JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good choice is Json.NET nuget package for work with JSON. I have create test method for you.

```
//Read your json file 
string json = File.ReadAllText("ABC.json");
//deserialize
F1P1X[][][] yourArrayOfArraysOfArrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<F1P1X[][][]>(json).ToList();

  public class F1P1X
  {
     public string Feature { get; set; }
     public string Point { get; set; }
     public string Coordinates { get; set; }
  }

  public static void Test()
  {
     F1P1X[] test1Array = new[] 
     {
        new F1P1X
        {
           Feature = "F1",
           Point = "P1",
           Coordinates = "X1"
        },
        new F1P1X
        {
           Feature = "F2",
           Point = "P2",
           Coordinates = "X2"
        },
     };

     F1P1X[] test2Array = new[] 
     {
        new F1P1X
        {
           Feature = "F3",
           Point = "P3",
           Coordinates = "X3"
        },
        new F1P1X
        {
           Feature = "F4",
           Point = "P4",
           Coordinates = "X4"
        },
     };

     F1P1X[][] test = {test1Array, test2Array};
     F1P1X[][] test2 = { test1Array, test2Array };
     F1P1X[][][] top = {test, test2};

     //array of arrays of arrays as JSON
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(top);
     List<F1P1X[][]> arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<F1P1X[][][]>(json).ToList();

     foreach (F1P1X[][] item in arrays)
     {
        foreach (F1P1X[] f1P1X in item)
        {
           foreach (F1P1X p1X in f1P1X)
           {
              //do some magic 
           }
        }
     }


     // or use linq
     var result = arrays.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Where(z => z.Coordinates == "X1")));
  }
```

This linq statement returns list of features

```
List<string> result = arrays.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Select(z => z.Feature))).ToList();
```